# Sending SMS without Intent on android issue

Tags: android, sms

I'm trying to send SMS in the background of android phone . I'm using this code along with the manifiest permessions :

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
 }






sendSMS(number, text);
```

Now the issue I have is when I try to send for a regular number (05239652203) for example it works perfetly , but when I try to send for a short number (5555) for example a pop up shows and says "This is application is trying to send SMS message click Confirm or cancel" something like that . Due to the nature of my application It requires sending the SMS in the background (I'm trying to develop an application that helps the phone owener to trace the phone if it was stolen) . So is there's any way to turn around this issue ?? and thanks in advance

Comment: I think that this is the phones issue because i developed an app that required sending an sms to a short no and this code worked perfectly for me. Try using it on a different device.

Comment: Did u use the same code ?

Comment: Yeah. And i sent the message to 51619.

Comment: I've just nailed it . If the number is 4 numbers or less it will trigger the popup otherwise it will work without triggering it